# Сравнение двумерного массива JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, for, find

Даны два массива:

```
array_1 = [
            {data: "2020-05-30",users:[user1]},
            {data: "2020-05-29",users:[user1]}
          ]
array_2 = [
            {data: "2020-05-25",users:[user1,user2,user3]},
            {data: "2020-05-28",users:[user4,user5,user3]},
            {data: "2020-05-29",users:[user2,user3,user1,]}
            {data: "2020-05-30",users:[user1]}
          ]
```

И мне нужно сравнить вхождение одного в другой, с глубиной, чтобы данное выражение выдало например  true (что первый массив входит во второй), хотелось бы увидеть предложения профессионалов, как можно это обыграть с малым количеством циклов, да, конечно можно это сделать через lodash с одним циклом и find, но думаю что можно обыграть как-то интереснее.

Использовал lodash и difference, сравнивает только он не учитывает индексы.

Спасибо, я только начинаю)

Comment: `сравнивает только он не учитывает индексы`, что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Что если они идут не в таком порядке - то он считает их различными

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял:

```js
function CreateUser(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

let user1 = new CreateUser("Иван");
let user2 = new CreateUser("Александр");
let user3 = new CreateUser("Михаил");
let user4 = new CreateUser("Анатолий");
let user5 = new CreateUser("Никита");

let array_1 = [
    {data: "2020-05-30",users:[user1]},
    {data: "2020-05-29",users:[user1]}
];
let array_2 = [
    {data: "2020-05-29",users:[user2,user3, user1]},
    {data: "2020-05-28",users:[user4,user5,user3]},
    {data: "2020-05-30",users:[user1]},
    {data: "2020-05-25",users:[user1,user2,user3]},
];

function compare(sub, main) {
  for(let i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) {
    let obj = main.find( item => item.data === sub[i].data); // (*)

    if(obj) {
      for(let j = 0; j < sub[i].users.length; j++) {
        if(!obj.users.includes(sub[i].users[j])) return false;
      }
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
 
  return true;
}

console.log(compare(array_1, array_2)); // true
array_2[2].users.pop();
console.log(compare(array_1, array_2)); // false
```

Чтобы учитывать индексы, можно в строке `(*)` проверять их равенство:

```
let obj = main.find( (item, index) => item.data === sub[i].data && index == i);
```